# If statement in Ruby giving me unexpected answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm playing around with the Ruby Twitter gem, which, for example, allows you to check if a Twitter user's account is locked. The user's account I am testing is locked.

If I do

```
@awish = Twitter.user("twitteruser").protected?
```

and then in a view do

```
 <%= @awish %>
```

it says "true"

However. when I try to write a method to test this and assign the response  to a variable depending on whether it's locked or not, it's telling me that it's "not locked", when I would be expecting it to say it's "locked". So I think I've screwed up this if/else statement somehow (note, I'm a bit of a noob)

Can you explain what I've done wrong?

```
def awisprotect
       @awish = Twitter.user("twitteruser").protected?
       if @awish == "true" 
        @answer = "locked" 
        else 
        @answer = "not locked"
        end

       render :js => "$('div.awishanswer').html(' #{ @answer } ');"
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "true" isn't a string, remove the quotes and it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

the `protected?` method should either return `true` or `false`.

(rather than `"true"` or `"false"`)

So your method can be much simpler.
(you also don't need an instance variable)

```
def awisprotect
  if Twitter.user("twitteruser").protected?
    answer = "locked" 
  else 
    answer = "not locked"
  end
  render :js => "$('div.awishanswer').html(' #{ answer } ');"
end
```